# SQL server time query day between 3am and 3am

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I have a case where a day is considered from 3 am to 3 am. I have to match the time from two different tables with a -10 and +10 min interval. In some cases, the time from a table happens to be `from 11:55 pm` to `11:59 pm`; however, in the other table, the record that should match has the same date but a time that ranges from `00:00 am` to `00:05 am`. Knowing that the two records have the same date, how can I match the time?

First table airingtime:

- Date - Date
- Program1 - varchar
- fromGmt - time
- ToGmt - time

Second table airingtime2:

- Date - Date
- Program2 - varchar
- ScheduleStart- time
- ScheduleEnd- time

I want to match program1 field to program 2 field by a join on the date and time :

```
…JOIN… airingtime at
    ON at.[fromgmt] BETWEEN dateadd(minute, -10, airingtime2[ScheduleStart])
                        AND dateadd(minute, +10, [Schedule:Asrun Start])
   AND at.[date] = airingtime2.[date]
```

But in some cases:

- table 1: From (00:00)
- table 2: From (23:54)

The code won't work since "00:00"< "23:54". However, they have the same date.

Comment: not sure what you are asking, can you provide some sample data and your desired output?

Comment: One range is four minutes while the other is five.

Comment: Do you have the logic sorted out the way you want if what is considered a day is midnight to midnight?

Comment: usually the solution for this case would be: `[fromgmt]  between dateadd(minute,-20,[ScheduleStart] ) and  dateadd(minute,20,[Schedulerun Start] )` but since one date is after mifnight and the other is before midnight . the code wont work

Comment: You could just `addDate(hour, -3, yourDateTimeColumn)` and compare the dates...

Comment: @ZoharPeled that is exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: I would the same problem for the 3am ( which will be 00:00 am ) after the transformation @ZoharPeled

Comment: Can you edit your question to include sample data as DDL+DML and desired results?